# How to prove inverse Laplace transform doesn't exist

Tags: laplace-transform

We can show that the integral doesn't exist when trying to find Laplace tranform of a function. Is there a way to show that a particular function cannot be obtained but performing Laplace transform on some other function?

Comment: See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1429363/8581)

Comment: If the function $f$ is piecewise continuous on $[0,c]$ and is of exponential order $\exp(ax)$ then $\lim F(s)$ gets zero when $s$ tends to $\infty$ where $F$ is the laplace transformation of $f$.