# Is the collection of Gaussian functions $\mathcal F=\{\exp(-ax^2):a\geq0\}$ a basis?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis

Is the collection of Gaussian functions $\mathcal F=\{\exp(-ax^2):a\geq0\}$ a basis for the space of all smooth functions on $\mathbb R^+$?

Seems that this collection is linearly independent. Is this also a basis?

EDIT: When I say basis, I am allowing infinite sums from this set, that is, given any smooth function $f$ on $\mathbb R^+$, do we have a measure $\mu_f$ such that $f(x)=\int_{supp(\mu)} \exp(-ax^2)d\mu_f(a)$ for every $x\in\mathbb R^+$? I am not sure what $\mathcal F$ would be called if this happens, is this still called a "basis"?

Comment: An iconic question! :)

Comment: What do you mean by a basis ? Are you interested if $\mathcal{F}$ is dense n $C_0^{(k)}(\mathbb{R}_+)$ ? If so you can make use of  the  Stone-Weierstrass theorem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The inverse Laplace transform of $f(\sqrt{x})$ is the density of the measure $\mu_f\,.$

***Theorem*** ([Bernstein](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernstein%27s_theorem_on_monotone_functions)). *For every completely monotone function $g:(0,\infty)\to\mathbb R$ there exists a unique measure $\mu$ on $[0,\infty)$ such that for every $x>0$
$$\tag{1}
g(x)=\int_0^\infty e^{-xa}\mu(da)\,.
$$
Conversely, whenever the RHS of (1) is finite for every $x>0$ then $g(x)$ is completely monotone.*

See also [1].

***Corollary***. *The measure $\mu_f$ with
$$
f(x)=\int_0^\infty e^{-ax^2}\mu_f(da)
$$
exists if and only if $x\mapsto f(\sqrt{x})$ is completely monotone.*

By definition this means that $x\mapsto f(\sqrt{x})$ is $C^\infty$ and
$$
(-1)^n\frac{d^n}{dx^n}f(\sqrt{x})\ge 0\quad\quad \forall n\in\mathbb N\cup \{0\}\text{ and }x>0\,.
$$

[1] R.L. Schilling, R. Song, Z. Vondracek, *Bernstein Functions*.